# Aligning text horizontally within a grid box

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to align horizontally the h4 tag "some other head" within my grid, as you can see right now they are not aligned.  Is there a way to do this within the grid box? Thanks!

Here is my example of code:

```
Current Code:

https://codepen.io/kjay125/pen/GRpQgbj
```

Comment: what do you want to do? Right aligned h4?

Comment: I see it is left aligned or am i missing something?

Comment: the h4 "some other head", is it possible to align them horizontally across the 3 grid boxes?

Comment: got it working?

Comment: Yes, is there a better way to do this? with the grid-box features?

Comment: Internally that also sets the css only. CSS is the core of styling. You better design your own than using the pre defined types.

Comment: Try this structure if you want it other way 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_equal_height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can do it in two ways: 

 1. If your text is static then add a fix height for p tag. Add this css:

    p {
    height: 220px;
    display:block;
    }    



2. But if it can be changed or by internationalization, it can get converted to different language and gets longer/shorter than you have to set the height of p through javascript/JS after the page is loaded. But the crux is, you have to set a fixed height of `<p>`.
```